# Controller actions for home, about and contact pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controllers

I've just started a project and created a `pages_controller` and within the controller I have this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def home

end

end
```

these are my routes:

```
  devise_for :users
  root to: "pages#home"
```

I created the pages controller thinking I can use it to have a home page, about page & contact page. From my limited experience, it seems that your actions within your controllers should stick to the `new,create,destroy,delete,show,index,edit and update`
Is it bad to name an action `Home, contact or about` like I've done above? What do you usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with not having 100% RESTful routes in a Rails application. Particularly for your exact use case, which is to collect a handful of "static" pages. You're absolutely on the right track. The only thing I would consider changing would be to break out the contact page to its own controller (`ContactPageSubmissions`, perhaps), if it has a form on it - if it is just contact information, I would leave that where it is, too.

Comment: I've added an about action in my controller, a pages/about view and a pages resource in my routes. How do I access this view on my browser? localhost:3000/about nor localhost:3000/pages/about seems to work and I can't see any available route when I search my rake routes output.

Comment: You will need to add a route for each relevant action, in your `config/routes.rb` file, like `get 'about' , to: 'pages#about' , as: :about`. Official docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  - good luck!

Comment: Hmm I was under the impression that 'resources' would make actions in a controller available. I guess 'resources' only makes available the RESTful actions in our Rails application?

Comment: Yeah, resources is for a set of RESTful routes.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of get 'about' , to: 'pages#about' , as: :about  but it didn't work.. I get an error when trying to run rails s

Comment: What is the error? Make sure your syntax follows the guide at  guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Something I like to do for static pages is to just use a single action, and use it to show different views. This is not very good for dynamic views:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "application#static", page: "home"

pages = %w(about contact)
for page in pages do
    get page, to: "application#static", page: page #-> routes all to `static` method in `ApplicationController`, with "page" param
end

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def static
    case params[:home]
    when "about"
       page = "about"
    when "contact"
       page = "contact"
    else
       page = "home"
    end
    render "pages/#{page}"
end
```

Then you'd make a folder in `views/pages` & make the required pages in there! DRY & simple!